# What is the most efficient way to submit and save a form with several ICollection items?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, icollection

I am having users fill out a form that requires a number of 'educational background' pieces of data:

```
public class EducationalBackground
{
    public int EducationalBackgroundID { get; set; }

    public string UniversityOrCollege { get; set; }

    public string AreaOfStudy { get; set; }

    public string Degree { get; set; }

    public int YearReceived { get; set; }

    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the model for the full Application:

```
public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }

    public Profile BasicInfoGatheredFromProfile { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EducationalBackground> EducationalBackground { get; set; }

    public bool WillingToTravel { get; set; }
}
```

I am working on making a page where users can fill out the full application and it will render a partial view that allows them to add an "educational background" piece of data up to however many they have.

What would be the most efficient way to allow users to add in indefinite number of "education background" pieces of information in this application?

What I am thinking:  I will need a ViewModel to allow for the IColleciton of EducationalBackground when I POST the form.  Is jQuery the cleanest way to add additional fields for 'educational background'?

An example POST action would be appreciated in addition to any information one is able to provide.

Comment: Have you checked this blog post about [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)? It's uses MVC2 but the same concepts apply for MVC3 as well.

Comment: @nemesv I have now.  Looks almost perfect.  They do not use IDs in their model - would I not need to use IDs?  or do they not use IDs for some other reason of which I am unaware?

Comment: @miscusermandude They **are** using ids. They stated using `HTML.TextBoxFor` "to avoid the need to build element IDs manually". By using this mechanism, MVC will assign the values in the form automagically to a parameter in your Action.